# Is there a word that describes a pre-wedding party?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

So there are many words that describe the event that takes place before the wedding: *stag do, hen do, bachelor party, bachelorette party*.

Is there a single word that encompasses all those things?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need at least two words here. I think *pre-wedding celebration* is OK, but could also include a rehearsal dinner, which you're excluding.

I'd suggest *last hurrah* or if you're in the UK, you could use *hag party* (which is a combination of *hen* and *stag*).

Answer (score 0):

Stag Party is often used in the UK to mean either of a Stag party or a Hen party, but generally the two are kept distinct, as they tend to be quite different in the nature of entertainment and activities.

Comment: I know what each means, I wondered if there was a term that encompassed both.

Comment: _Rehearsal Dinner_.

Comment: That's nothing to do with Stag or Hen dos.

Comment: Piers - yes. Stag Party can encompass them both!

Comment: I was referring to @John Lawler's comment.

Comment: That depends on what's being rehearsed, I should think.